# Trigger Java from Jasperstudio

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following Java code, which will modify the width of a rectangle by modifying  JRXML. But how do I call the Java code when the report runs? Scriptlet didn't help much. Is there a way to call the Java/jar file in studio to dynamically change the width of text object?

```
public class widthAdjust {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JasperDesign design;
    try {
        design = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\GanttChart_Java.jrxml");
    System.out.println(design);
    JRField[] fields = design.getFields();
    JRVariable[] variables =  design.getVariables();

    int newWidth = 100;
    int newX = 100;
    JRDesignBand baseBand = (JRDesignBand) design.getSummary();
    JRElement[] elements = baseBand.getElements();
    System.out.println(elements);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < elements.length; counter++) {
        JRDesignElement element = (JRDesignElement) elements[counter];
            element.setWidth(newWidth);
            element.setX(newX);
    }
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(design,"C:\\GanttChart_Java.jasper");
    JasperCompileManager.writeReportToXmlFile("C:\\GanttChart_Java.jasper","C:\\GanttChart_Java.jrxml");
    JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\GanttChart_Java.jrxml");
} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

Comment: fixed code and spelling

Answer (score 0):

To change the attributes of an element, the best way is to run your Java code and use the Jasper API.

The other way around, to call Java code out of your .jasper-report (as far as I understood the case) is not possible, since the jasper file is already a compiled report with specific widths.